# Ruby on Rails: How to Render Partial in a view via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, partial

I have a 'project' form as a partial. I'm trying to use jquery to render the partial when user clicks a button:

```
$('.projects').append("<%= render partial: 'projects/project') %>").html_safe
```

But using the above code is literally rendering "<%= render partial: 'projects/project') %>" on the page instead of the actual partial.

Comment: I think your javascript file doesn't have the `erb` extension in it, if it is then rename from `file.js` to `file.js.erb`

Comment: what's the name of this file anyways? cause it looks like js but you added `.html_safe` which is ruby, and you said form partial, so idk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe renaming your file extension from `xxx.js` to `xxx.js.erb` might solve your problem.

Comment: I think Bernie is correct.  If the file ends in erb, then rails will render the view.  If not, then it just treats it as any other static file.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$('#projects').html('<%= escape_javascript render 'projects/project' %>');
```

**Note:** As `Bernie Chiu` suggested you need to change file extension from `xxx.js` to `xxx.js.erb`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('.projects').append("<%= j render partial: 'projects/project') %>");
```

`j` is the alias for `escape_javascript`.

See documentation for [escape_javascript](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) helper.